# Does maven aggregation merge pom properties like inheritance?

Tags: java, maven

Because [it's](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#project-aggregation) been said that: `Project Aggregation is similar to Project Inheritance`, i would assume that when we specify a module in a parent pom.xml we would merge it's information(e.g. dependencies) with it's child pom's. However this does not appear to be the case. So how exactly are these two mechanisms similair and does aggregation even merge it's information with it's child elements at all?

Comment: Aggregation is about allowing Maven lifecycle commands to be executed independently against several projects at one time. One executes the lifecycle command against the parent and all subprojects (in the form of _Modules_) have the same command executed against them. There is no "_inheritance_" of anything from the child or from the parent module to the Chile modules.

Comment: Yes i see. These concepts seem to have different purposes. But then how exactly are these two mechanism "similair" if they seem to do completely different things?

Comment: they are similar is that they both have consequences in the form of cumulative maven actions on the project's module structure. In the case of aggregation the consequence is fewer maven interactions for each module while with inheritance the consequence is shared maven dependencies between modules.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK aggregation does not "transfer" anything to the child POMs.

Hence you usually combine aggregation with inheritance.